# Firebase Pricing: Do quotas include all projects?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Do quotas include all projects or are they separate for each firebase/google cloud project?

I am asking this question because I am wondering if I should include multiple apps in one project to keep the price down. Regarding organization, splitting up the apps into multiple projects would be better.

Currently I have an project for an App and another project on Google Cloud to host a website. (All apps will use the same website)

Thanks for your help! *(I know this is not a programming question, but it is important to know as a programmer using firebase)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each project is treated separately. I have multiple projects each on the paid Blaze plans and they each have their own quotas... all on the same Google Payments account. Each month you get an invoice for your Google Payments account that has a total charge, and it breaks that charge down not only into each project, but also the portions of each project (*hosting, storage, cloud functions, etc...*)

Comment: I'm sorry, can you make it clear for me? I have two projects on firebase. I remember that the limits of Firebase Storage, for example, is 5GB. What does it mean? I have free 5GB for all my projects or 5GB is reserved for every project?

Comment: @EgorRandomize It would be 5 GB per project

Comment: What if my hosting will exceed but my firestore is in the limits, will my firestore will still work I am using free plan

Comment: @Noobdeveloper I'm not certain, I haven't come across that scenario and a quick google search doesn't turn up any obvious answers. Feel free to post a separate question or experiment yourself :)